# epoch time to human readable date

Tags: python, pandas

```
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
cst_time = []
for i in (data3['received_time']):
    cst_time.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(i,tz))
data3['Date'] = pd.DataFrame(cst_time)
```

Error:

> C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14320\1298578616.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats [in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: There's a huge amount of questions/answers regarding this issue available. Please look if they provide an answer to your problem before asking a question. And please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).